# Apple Reject app for fund raising to charities

Tags: appstore-approval

From my binary I have removed stripe payment but apple rejected the app by giving the below description

We noticed that your app or its metadata provides access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, we have continued to find that the Stripe payment mechanism is still present within the binary of your app.